# Trying to create a unique Excel autofill pattern

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to edit the autofill pattern?

Specifically I am trying to have excel understand that what I want to do is create a column with the data set pattern,

1
1
2
2
3
3
...
100
100

but without having to manually type out the data in each cell. The first data point itself is a variable amount however the pattern will always be the same. The first data point will be duplicated in the cell below and the next sequential increment will follow then be duplicated and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your question.  You have a good question, IMHO, but it's not really appropriate for Stack Overflow's *programming* focus.  I would recommend opening this question on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the first cell and copy down 200 rows:

```
=INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/2)+1
```

for the variable start change the `+1` to the first number or cell reference desired.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first value is variable:

```
A3 = IF(A1=A2,A2+1 ,A2)
```

Where `A1 = Header` and `A2` is your variable value